# Сравнить дату в php?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть список заявок, у которых есть дата в таком типе. 2015-11-11. В БД тип даты в date.

Как правильно реализовать такую схему.

1) Если дата из БД равна сегодняшней дате, то поменять значение в поле archive на 1.

2) Как делать проверку даты по сегодняшней дате. Точнее в какой момент делать проверку? Писать какой то скрипт который каждый день будет запускаться и переводить заявки в архив?

Спасибо.

**UPD** По второму вопрос думаю отпадает. На хостинге есть cron. Можно написать скрипт который будет проверять дату с сегодняшней и поставить в задачу Cron.
Вот теперь вопрос, как правильно написать условие по проверке сегодняшней даты с датой из БД.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сегодняшнюю дату можно получить конструкцией из вызовов двух функций [`date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) и [`now()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8abe0/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (d date, archive int);
insert into t values
   ('2015-11-22', 0)
  ,('2015-11-23', 0);

update t set archive = 1 where d = date(now());
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8abe0/1/0)**:

```
|                          d | archive |
|----------------------------|---------|
| November, 22 2015 00:00:00 |       1 |
| November, 23 2015 00:00:00 |       0 |
```

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
UPDATE
    таблица
SET
    archive = IF( поле_с_датой = DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d' ), 1, 0 )
WHERE
    archive != 1 AND условия;
```

В "условиях" можно конкретизировать строки. Либо же можно сделать update по всем полям таблицы, и отдельным криптом запускать по крону раз в сутки например. Либо же воспользоваться встроенным планировщиком событий в MySQL (5.1+)